# Как подать вибросигнал в приложении

Tags: java, android, android-notification

При нажатии на кнопку мне нужно подать пользователю вибро сигнал (кнопка нажата)

Я могу послать ему звуковой сигнал таким образом:

```
 Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                    notification);
            r.play();
```

Вопрос: можно ли как то  подобным образом послать вибро сигнал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В гугле написано так:

```
 Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 vibrator.vibrate(timeInMillies);
```

Ну и пермишн

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```